# Swift programming without using mac

Tags: macos

I am new to mobile application development and I have decided to use Swift for iOS development but I don't want to buy a Mac , can I install macOS on another computer and start developing?
 Thanks

Comment: try flutter which uses dart programming language, with this you can develop apps for both iOS and Andriod.

Answer (score 2):

No, macOS is only licensed for use on Apple Mac hardware.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways if you want to do IOS development.

1. First one is to work with cross-platform like Flutter or React Native.
2. Use Virtual Machine which can enable you to use MacOS in windows but it is very slow.

So If you want to do IOS development natively MacOS hardware are recommended. You can opt-in for cheap options like used `Mac` or `Mac Mini`